# Short story about advertising replacing music

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, music

I remember a short story about a future where advertising jingles were the only type of music still performed.   If I recall, one musician rediscovered the idea that music could exist by itself and sets off an artistic revolution.  I read the story ~35 years ago but it could have been older.  Does anyone know the title or author?

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but a similar idea makes a brief appearance in the *Demolition Man* movie with Sly Stallone.

Comment: Sounds like it might be Panel Game by Brian Aldiss, but I can't find my copy of Space, Time and Nathaniel right now so I can't confirm for certain.

Answer (score 5):

*[Tunesmith](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92980.Eye_for_Eye_The_Tunesmith)* by Lloyd Biggle Jr.

Erlin Baque is the last true musician on Earth. Commercial jingles have replaced real art. The Performers' Guild enforces mediocrity on pain of blacklisting. . . But Baque has one weapon his enemies cannot resist: his music. (from Pastebin)

[image]