# Short Story Set In Future Where Jingles Become Pop Music?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

I think it might be by Ray Bradbury.

Music has been reduced to clips from jingles/commercials. There's a machine that writes the songs, but protagonist goes to work in small club/bar & becomes very successful.

Comment: https://youtu.be/hVYArjS-Ee0?t=17 - Did somebody say *mini-tunes*?

Comment: Aaaaw, @Valorum took the YouTube link right out of my keyboard. Anyway, welcome to the site, and while you have a good start here, could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 6):

Possibly *The Tunesmith* by Lloyd Biggle Jr, a novelette published in *If*, August 1957, [scan](https://archive.org/details/1957-08_IF_modified/page/n5) available on the Internet Archive, as well as [a transcript](https://archive.org/stream/1957-08_IF_modified/1957-08_IF_modified_djvu.txt).

Extracts:

> He picked up the Com lyric again,  and his mind began to shape the 
>   thread of a melody.
>
> “If your flyer jerks and clowns,  if it has its ups and downs, ups and
>   downs, ups and downs, you need a  WARING!”
>
> He hummed softly to himself,  sketching a musical line that  swooped
>   and jerked like an erratic  flyer. Word painting, it was called,  back
>   when words and tones meant  something. Back when the B-A-C-H  Baque
>   was underscoring such grandiose concepts as heaven and hell.

...

> Baque cleared  a corner for himself and sat down  wearily, stretching
>   his long legs out  under the table.
>
> “Damn Hulsey,” he muttered.  “Damn sponsors. Damn visiscope.  Damn
>   Corns.”
>
> Compose something. You’re not  a hack, like the other tunesmiths.  You
>   don’t punch your melodies out  on a harmonizer’s keyboard and let  a
>   machine harmonize them for you.  You’re a musician, not a melody 
>   monger. Write some music. Write a  — a sonata, for multichord. Take 
>   the time now, and compose something.

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] jingles` which returned, among others, [Short story about advertising replacing music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/44854)

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the chekmark on the left.